# Python: web scraping being blocked

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Apologies if I miss out any information. I'm a bit of a novice and will do my best to explain myself.

I am doing a personal project to learn coding and more specifically Python. I had got quite busy at work over the last couple weeks and wasn't able to do my project in that time. When I have come back to my code it no longer works like it did before. I've been trying to problem solve what the issue is to understand how the website is blocking me.

From what I can work out I can scrape data from a single page but once I begin to take out more than just one piece of data and use a while loop I get a 404 return rather than 200.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = f"https://www.zoopla.co.uk/house-prices/edinburgh/"
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content
soup = bs(html, "lxml")
address = soup.find_all("div", class_="c-imWYEM c-imWYEM-pnwXf-hasUprn-true")
for div in address:
    (div.get_text(strip=True))
print(response)
```

I had built my code up a lot more to get various bits of data and also wanted to start sorting it into a DataFrame. This is the code that was previously working that is now giving me an error message.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt
import time

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.157 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Referer": "https://google.co.uk",
    "DNT": "1"
}

page = 1
scotland_houses = []
while page != 3:
    url = f"https://www.zoopla.co.uk/house-prices/Edinburgh/?pn={page}"
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    html = response.content
    soup = bs(html, "lxml")
    for address in soup.find_all("div", class_="c-imWYEM c-imWYEM-pnwXf-hasUprn-true"):
        time.sleep(20)
        scotland_house = {}
        # Getting the address
        scotland_house["Address"] = address.h3.get_text(strip=True)
        # Getting each addresses unique URL
        scotland_house_url = f'https://www.zoopla.co.uk{address.find("a")["href"]}'
        scotland_house["URL"] = scotland_house_url
        scotland_house_url_response = requests.get(
            scotland_house_url, headers=headers)
        scotland_house_soup = bs(scotland_house_url_response.content, 'lxml')
        # Lists status of the property
        try:
            scotland_house["Status"] = [status.get_text(strip=True) for status in scotland_house_soup.find_all(
                "span", class_="css-1jwes4a-Tag-Status-TimelineBadge e15fknhb0")]
        except AttributeError:
            scotland_house["Status"] = ""
        # Lists the date of the status of the property
        try:
            scotland_house["Status Date"] = [status_date.get_text(strip=True) for status_date in scotland_house_soup.find_all(
                "p", class_="css-11dmkz9-Text-StyledDateText e15fknhb1")]
        except AttributeError:
            scotland_house["Status Date"] = ""
        # Lists the value of the property
        try:
            scotland_house["Value (£)"] = [value.get_text(strip=True).replace(",", "").replace("£", "") for value in scotland_house_soup.find_all(
                "p", class_="css-1x01gac-Text eczcs4p0")]
        except AttributeError:
            scotland_house["Value"] = ""
        scotland_houses.append(scotland_house)
    page = page + 1

# for house in scotland_houses[:]:
#     print(house)

# houses_df = pd.DataFrame(scotland_houses)
# houses_df['ID'] = houses_df.index + 1
# houses_df = houses_df.set_index(['ID']).apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index()
# houses_df[['Address', 'Town', 'Postcode']
#           ] = houses_df['Address'].str.split(',', expand=True)
# houses_df['Status Date'] = pd.to_datetime(
#     houses_df['Status Date'], format='%B %Y', errors='coerce')
# houses_df["Value (£)"] = houses_df['Value (£)'].astype(str).astype(float)
# print(houses_df)
# print(houses_df.dtypes)

print(response)
```

I thought it was maybe something to do with my user-agent at first but I've tried changing that and it doesn't work. It originally was giving me a 404 result when I stripped the code right back to just this:

```
page = 1
addresses = []
while page != 2:
    url = f"https://www.zoopla.co.uk/house-prices/edinburgh/?pn={page}"
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(response)
    html = response.content
    soup = bs(html, "lxml")
    for h3 in soup.find_all("h3", class_="c-hWRJdU"):
        addresses.append(h3.get_text(strip=True))
    page = page + 1

for address in addresses[:]:
    print(address)
```

However, I changed the part that says Edinburgh in the url to Glasgow and it worked for me. I then changed it back to Edinburgh at that worked for me as well. I just can't get it to work on my larger bit of code that I'm trying to use. Any help or advice what I can try would be much appreciated.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

The same exact thing happened to me (I think the website realized and enhanced the security). Anyway, I'm now exploring ways to get around that by saving the webpage html.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32386752)

Answer (score -1):

Scraping websites without permission is illegal, they protect their data by analysing the behavior of the request for example if it's repetitive from the same IP address with the same User-Agent (Browser's stuff) the server will return some kind of error status codes like you mentiened or like 429 for too many requets or like some CloudFlare's error codes.

You should try to use some kind of proxies like ScrapeOwl or ProxyCrawl to bypass their protection just to check where the issue is coming from.

Comment: "*Scraping websites without permission is illegal*" ***Citation needed!*** This is a pretty extreme claim to make considering many courts around the world have actually affirmed the opposite (see [*hiQ vs. LinkedIn*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HiQ_Labs_v._LinkedIn) (U.S.A.), *RyanAir vs. PR Aviation* (EU)) - that publicly-available pages and the data on them are fair game *in the eyes of the law* provided that the use of the data is in line with copyright law. (1/2)

Comment: While sites may have clauses in their Terms of Service to prohibit these activities, they are not *illegal* at all, and are instead largely considered a *civil* matter in most jurisdictions. Your statement seems to imply that scraping ANY content without explicit permission is illegal UNDER LAW, which is absolutely NOT the case. Please cite verifiable sources when making claims like this, or remove them from your answer. (2/2)

Comment: In any event, this answer does not fully answer the question. It's probably better as a comment on the original post instead.